# How to keep image inside div without stretching or clinching it?

Tags: css

I have this html:

```
<div class="postcard-container">
    <div id="postcard-classic" class="postcard-classic">
        <div class="postcard-classic-img">
            <img ng-src="{{postcard.image.cropped}}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this css:

```
.postcard-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.postcard-classic {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url("../img/frames/postcard_00.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 10px;  
}

.postcard-classic-img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I want my image to start at the top left corner. If it is a very small picture it should be climped to the top left corner and if it is too big i want the overflow not to be shown. Lets take an example if the image is too big. My goal is this:

[image]

Where blue is the image and red the div. What i got from my code posted above is the following if the picture is too big:

[image]

How can i solve this?

**EDIT**

Thats how far i am right now: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r9Lorfp/). As you can see the image is not starting at the top left corner and the overflow is not hidden.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: This is exactly what you want to do : https://www.exratione.com/2011/09/how-to-overflow-a-background-image-using-css3/

Comment: updated with a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you desire should be the default behavior of background image in a div. So you should only need the backround-image and background-repeat properties.

```
.postcard-classic {
  background-image: url("../img/frames/postcard_00.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Yes, what I was saying is remove everything else from it.

Comment: cant do that. its needed for other styling stuff. I posted a working solution with fiddle example.

Comment: Your solution appears to shrink the photo to fit in the box which you could have done simply by setting a size on the image itself and adding a yellow border. What you were originally asking is to cut off the picture at the size of the parent div, which is different than your solution. Also you originally used a background image in the question, but in your solution you are using an image tag nested in a div which will also behave differently. If you are happy with your solution, that's great. If not can you clarify what your end goal is?

Comment: its alright like that. the background image i used had no influence on what i wanted. in the example i just replaced the background image with a background color (yellow). important was the position of the image. the shrinking of the photo was an accident but it appeared to be an even better solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Youd shouldnt specify any value to width

```
 .postcard-classic-img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: leaving out the width leads to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i can live with that solution:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08qq5d71/)

```
.postcard-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    padding: 20px;
}

.postcard-classic {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.postcard-classic-img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 8%;
    right: 8%;
}

.postcard-classic-img img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex solutions

```
.postcard-classic-img{
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    overflow:hidden
}
.postcard-classic-img img{
     flex-shrink:0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```